# Chrome Developer Tools: Can not open context menu for CSS sources

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

The title pretty much explains my problem.

Please take a look at the screenshot:

[image]

It's supposed to open a context menu giving a link to the source and stuff when I right-click on the link in the red rectangle, but nothing happens.

I'm using Chrome stable Version 34.0.1847.131 m, and this wasn't an error in the older versions.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** Chromium team noticed and fixed this bug somewhere in the recent versions. I am using v53.x now, and this bug doesn't appear to happen anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to **right click** on the link?
You have to ***left click*** on that link to go to the source, which will appear in `Sources` tab of dev tool.

Comment: I know about the left click and I don't want to go to the `Sources` tab! I just want the context-menu to open! Please note that this context-menu would always open on the older versions: http://aksup.ir/images/ixskfkc7fnmtwgq8akso.jpg

Comment: Then it might be removed from newer versions, because I'm also not getting context menu in version 35.0.1916.114 m, or it's a bug.

Comment: They must be so stupid if they've removed it intentionally! I've reported this, but there are no answers so far. Could you please report it too?

Comment: I reported it from the browser. Have you reported in Google Product Forum?

Comment: No, I've only reported from the browser too.

Comment: Then you may report in https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/chrome Google Product Forum - Google Chrome. You will probably get an answer.

Comment: I reported the bug, and it has been fixed since.